# jquery get the input box value

Tags: jquery

I have multiple text boxes and I am trying to get the value of text boxes based on button click, and only the value of text box should be shown.

```
// my html code here
<div class="addText">
// get the input box value
<input type="text" id="textVal" placeholder="Enter Text" class="enter-text" name="">
// div of buttons say add and update text
<div class="buttonset">
    // add button
    <button id="addTextBTN" class="left">ADD TEXT</button>
    // update button
    <button id="updateBTN" class="right">UPDATE TEXT</button>                                   
</div>
```

```
// below code i tried but not able to get the previous text box value

// button click event here
jq('body').on(opc_EventType, '#addTextBTN', function() {

// getting the text box value here 
var val = jq(this).prev().prev("input[type=text]").val();
// print on console
console.log(val);
```

Comment: Harsh, used textbox id to get value of textbox.

Comment: what is `opc_EventType`?

Comment: Using .prev(), .parent() etc for such purposes is not the best thing. Your markup can change, your events may be bubbled at some point etc. Use class/id selectors instead.

Comment: opc_EventType is to read the event

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to use `.parent().prev()` to target the input element.

Second, if you want it to work with a click event, use `.on("click", '#addTextBTN', function()`

Third, what is `opc_EventType`?

```
var jq = $;
// button click event here
jq('body').on("click", '#addTextBTN', function() {

  // getting the text box value here 
  var val = jq(this).parent().prev("input[type=text]").val();
  // print on console
  console.log(val);
})
```

**Working Demo**

```js
var jq = $;
// button click event here
jq('body').on("click", '#addTextBTN', function() {

  // getting the text box value here 
  var val = jq(this).parent().prev("input[type=text]").val();
  // print on console
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="addText">

  <input type="text" id="textVal" placeholder="Enter Text" class="enter-text" name="">
  <div class="buttonset">
    <button id="addTextBTN" class="left">ADD TEXT</button>
    <button id="updateBTN" class="right">UPDATE TEXT</button>
  </div>
```